# error in buffering in QGIS

Tags: qgis, buffer

1. I am using qgis 2.8.9 wien version.
2. windows 10 home 64-bit operating sysytem.
3. vector layer: Kml file,Line string
   CRS: WGS 84, EPSG:4326, is the base file for which buffer zone is to mark.
4. for the need of buffer in meters, I saved the file using "save as" option and saved it as "esri shapefile", where i changed the CRS to NAD 83/Maryland, EPSG:26985. In order to get the buffer zone in meters.
5. After that selected VECTOR-GEOPROCESSING TOOLS-BUFFERS.
6. In Buffer option in the slot of "BUFFER DISTANCE", I have filled 1 meter. Because i want the buffer zone of 1 meter, which is shown in below figure:
   [image]
7. I got the buffer zone in meters but when i cross checked it, it showing the distance of 0.95m. means there is 0.05m error for 1mtr. which is shown in below figure:
   [image]
8. For 1mtr it is 0.05m error. For 15000m its is showning much more error.
9. Since i am doing the project of noise modeling. single meter is also important to me.

My question is why this error is occuring?
what is the solution for this?

Comment: Try changing your **Projection CRS** from `EPSG:4326` to `EPSG:26985` and try measuring the distance again.

Comment: Thank you for your reply joseph, I went through your solution but there also i dint get an accurate answer.

Comment: Show some source geometries and buffered geometries as WKT.

Comment: Consider also that the **Measure line** tool is not an accurate way for measuring an exacting distance. I think that the @Joseph's suggest should be the best one to apply.

Comment: followed your suggestion, but there is no changes in result

Comment: I guess that buffer is computed for each vertex and they are moved perpendicularly compered to the tangent. It may not be extremely exact if there are long distances between the vertices. I suggest to densify the source geometries to have reasonably many vertices.

Comment: will you please tell me, how to do that?

Comment: Processing toolbox -> Densify geometries given an interval

Comment: And if you have access to GRASS you can try v.buffer.distance, to see if you obtain the same issue.

Comment: Tried victor..still the same result

Comment: Interresting problem, however you state that you have an error of 0.05m, but the figure shows 1.89m. Does this not mean you have an error of 0.89m? Or is the buffer shown larger than one meter? I have had this problem myself but the only solution that I can think of is the difference in CRS's. The measuring tool, to my knowledge, measures the project not the layer. So I'm thinking there lays your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your reply konan, since it is buffering when we input 1 mtr, it will give 1mtr buffer both sides. so it is showing 1.89m distance. I have tried by keeping both the projected layer and base layer same. But no difference konan. will you please tell me how you came out with this error?

Comment: Is the canvas CRS the same as the layer CRS? I see on your screen shot OTF is active!

Comment: Your screenshot shows coordinates around 74.1 E 18.5 N. This is somewhere in India, far away from the area of use for NAD83/Maryland. Try a CRS suitable for your area.

Answer (score -2):

I'm pretty sure you can't carry out a buffer operation on a kml. Convert to a shapefile first and try that. At the same time convert the projection to a utm form, for instance for Australia EPSG 28355 is a utm.

Comment: OP specified that they already converted to an esri shapefile in a UTM projection.